# "Pattern matching" and extracting in C

Tags: c, pattern-matching

I need to parse a lot of filenames (up to 250000 I guess), including the path, and extract some parts out of it.

Here is an example:

Original: `/my/complete/path/to/80/01/a9/1d.pdf`

Needed: `8001a91d`

The "pattern" I am looking for will always begin with "/8". The parts I need to extract form an 8 hex-digits string.

My idea is the following (simplyfied for demonstration):

```
/* original argument */
char *path = "/my/complete/path/to/80/01/a9/1d.pdf";

/* pointer to substring */
char *begin = NULL;

/* final char array to be build */
char *hex = (char*)malloc(9);

/* find "pattern" */
begin = strstr(path, "/8");
if(begin == NULL)
    return 1;

/* jump to first needed character */
begin++;

/* copy the needed characters to target char array */
strncpy(hex,   begin,   2);
strncpy(hex+2, begin+3, 2);
strncpy(hex+4, begin+6, 2);
strncpy(hex+6, begin+9, 2);
strncpy(hex+8, "\0",    1);     

/* print final char array */
printf("%s\n", hex);
```

This works. I just have the feeling it is not the most clever way. And that there might be some traps I don't see myself.

So, does someone have suggestions what could be dangerous with this pointer-shifting manner? What would be an improvement in your opinion?

Does C provide a functionality to do it like so `s|/(8.)/(..)/(..)/(..)\.|\1\2\3\4|` ? If I remember right some scripting languages have a feature like that; if you know what I mean.

Comment: I think you're doing it mostly right but would replace the `strncpy`s with plain assignments and confine that operation in a function where I don't need to see them.

Comment: You mean like this `hex[0] = begin[0];`?

Comment: Yup. But it's more a matter of taste, what looks fine to me might look horrendous to you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'll stick to the pointers a bit - just for training

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C itself doesn't provide this, but you can use POSIX regex. It's a full-featured regular expression library. But for a pattern as simple as yours, this probably is the best way.

BTW, prefer `memcpy` to `strncpy`. Very few people know what `strncpy` is good for. And I'm not one of them.

Comment: So, `memcpy` is the good sibling? I don't see any difference on the first look, but I'll dig a bit into it. thanks!

Comment: `memcpy` just copies memory. `strncpy` may or may not try to add a terminating `\0`, by a mysterious set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case of just matching `/8./../../..` I'd personally go for the `strstr()` solution myself (no external dependency required).  If the rules become more though, you could try a lexer ([flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) and friends), they support regular expressions.

In your case something like this:

```
h2           [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}
mymatch      (/{h2}){4}
```

could work.  You'd have to set buffers to the match by side effect though as lexers typically return token identifiers.

Anyway, you'd gain the power of regexps without the dependencies but at the expense of generated (read: unreadable) code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* original argument */
char *path = "/my/complete/path/to/80/01/a9/1d.pdf";
char *begin;
char hex[9];
size_t len;

/* find "pattern" */
begin = strstr(path, "/8");
if (!begin) return 1;

// sanity check
len = strlen(begin);
if (len < 12) return 2; 

   // more sanity
if (begin[3] != '/' || begin[6] != '/' ||  begin[9] != '/' ) return 3;

memcpy(hex,   begin+1, 2);
memcpy(hex+2, begin+4, 2);
memcpy(hex+4, begin+7, 2);
memcpy(hex+6, begin+10, 2);
       hex[8] = 0;     

   // For additional sanity, you could check for valid hex characters here
/* print final char array */
printf("%s\n", hex);
```

Comment: Thank you. That's nearly exactly what my unmodified code looks like :-)

Comment: Then, why did you modify it? You actually removed the checks before posting ?

Comment: Yes. They are not part of the question, and I tried to bring it down to what I want to ask. Like I also left out the rest (includes, functions, ...).

Comment: @Sascha It's probably better to show the *real* code, or at least indicate omissions `...`. But for one-line checks, marking the omission takes just as much space, so better to leave it in.

Comment: @luser droog: I thought that telling that it is not the complete code would be enough - like I said I wanted to put the focus on the extration from the "string"... but thank you very much. I'll keep it in mind for future questions!